# document.getElementById can't find qUnit DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, qunit

I'm trying to get a reference to a DOM object created by qUnit, with no luck. It works just fine with a "home made" DOM element. I have made a [test site](http://myinnerouterworldsimulator.neocities.org/qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element/index.html) to illustrate the problem. Turn on Firebug or other logging window when visiting the site.

This is the code of the website:

```js
window.onload = function() {

 var qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element = document.getElementById("qunit-testrunner-toolbar");
 console.log("qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element: ", qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element);

 var test_element = document.getElementById("test_element");
 console.log("test_element: ", test_element);
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing 'require' error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>See console for output</p>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <p id="test_element">Test element</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It won't work like this**

I am not talking about `qunit` but `document.getElementById("qunit-testrunner-toolbar");` will return null because there are no element present in this html.

If you are particularly asking how to get actual id and not `null`

You may, ***add your original script file in this html*** and then `var qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element = document.getElementById("qunit-testrunner-toolbar");` will `console` it in `indexjs` **or** if you can include `<iframe>` in your test html you can do

`<iframe src="urlWithinYourDomain.html" style="display:none" id="iframeId"></iframe>` 
and in indexjs

`var qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.getElementById('qunit-testrunner-toolbar');` if you like html way.

Comment: You're right that the DOM element never materialises in the toy example I gave in my question. In my effort to isolate the issue, I also lost the bug itself :/
In my real code, the DOM element actually *do* materialise.
I just realised that I must be dealing with a timing issue. If I use window.setTimeout to push my query two seconds into the future, I become the happy owner of a reference to the `qunit-testrunner-toolbar` DOM element :)
I now wonder how I'd do this in a more beautiful manner. How do I know when the qUnit DOM elements are ready? But, that'll be for another question.